# Show the current year in an email through AMPscript

Tags: ampscript, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I've been trying to dynamically change the year of the copyright in an e-mail template in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

I've tried code snippets from the internet but none of it is working.

```
%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
%%Now()%%
```

and even non AMPscript:

```
YEAR(TODAY())
```

But when I receive the email this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMn5I.jpg

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: Ok thank you, didn't know where to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [xtyear](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/) personalization string.

You'd use it like this:

```
&copy; %%xtyear%% sprignaturemoves.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If your email template is built using AMPscript you can use the following:

```
%%[
/* AMPscript */
   SET @CurrentYear = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
]%%

/* The Variable in the email body */

%%= v(@CurrentYear) =%%
```

Now() displays the current system date and time (1/1/2020  10:00:00). Adding the formatting reduces the value down to just the year.